# Как реализовать веб-авторизацию для приложения

Tags: c++

Кто бы мог подсказать популярный и качественный веб-интерфейс с доступным исходным кодом для `клиент <> сервер` (по принципу `Steam, Origin`), где есть онлайновая проверка по вводу данных (логин/пароль) т.е. связь с сервером.

И, на сколько я понял, данные передаются через сокет (`TCP, UDP`) и как быть уверенным, в том что они - закриптованы и имеют достойную защиту (например от перехвата).

Comment: Так ведь steam-клиент реализован, как встроенный браузер, а серверная часть, полагаю, заделана традиционными методами, как любой другой сайт.

Comment: "Веб-авторизация" с шифрованием напрашивается на банальный HTTPS.

Comment: @alexis031182 есть ли какие то заготовки по браузерам подобного рода на C++ . Немного дополню вопрос 
1.Как будет выглядеть связь между пользователем и сайтом и через что она будет передаваться(Socket TCP, без шифра ?) и как будет выглядеть пакет, т.е что помешает не доброжелателю сэмулировать пакет которые ожидает приложение на стороне пользователя(т.е клиентское), чтобы обойти проверку по IP или HWID ?
2.Как выглядит место получения данных на сервере, это 1 общий канал на который поступают запросы пользователей

Comment: @LighFusion, про "заготовки" мне не очень понятно. Разработкой непосредственно браузеров я не занимался. Другое дело, что функционал таковой уже имеется в популярных фреймворках для C++. Например в Qt. Теперь по поводу Ваших уточняющих вопросов. 1. Используйте https (об этом Вам прямо сказал D-side чуть выше), трафик будет зашифрован. Никто ничего не подменит, т.к. не будет смысла. 2. Это один общий порт, а соединений будет по числу пользователей. Http/https - это по сути использование тех же сокетов.

Comment: @LighFusion, вынесите свои уточнения в текст вопроса. Сейчас он слишком общий, а они позволят хотя бы отчасти придти к конкретизации. Это в свою очередь даст возможность участникам сориентироваться в том, что именно Вас интересует.

Comment: Смотря что вообще подразумевается под подменой данных. Подменить данные можно всегда. Никакой https от этого не спасет. Просто необходимо проверять данные на сервере. Причем проверять и их целостность и их правильность. Например, Вы использовали https протокол для передачи данных по защищенному каналу. Но сейчас также очень "модно" использовать для написания программ языки программирования (ЯП), которые не компилируются в машинный код (а то и вообще скриптовые). Байт-код такого клиента очень легко поддается "реверсинжинирингу" (или по -русски в большинстве своем декомпиляции для вредительства)

Comment: Уже в полученном по факту исходном коде я могу отсылать любые данные. И как будет шифроваться канал передачи данных при этом не будет уже иметь никакого значения. Ну или как пример, перехват шифрованных данных где-то посередине пути и их повреждение. Как от этого защитит протокол? Никак. Проверка и только проверка на сервере. И да, декомпилировать можно любой код, и машинный в том числе. Но разобраться в нем на порядок сложнее. И тратить уйму времени ради забавы человек с соответствующими знаниями не станет.

Comment: @MaxZS Мне главное чтобы было сложнее во всем этом разобраться, если захотят взломать, к примеру может было бы лучше отсылать саму программу по частям  - вместе с каким то мусором, и собирать на стороне клиента, только если его пк имеет нужные данные это как пример.

Comment: Забудьте об этом. Гарантированной защиты нет. Вопрос только в целесообразности реверс инжиниринга. Для этого Ваша программа должна быть очень и очень ценной и интересной. На сегодняшний день большинство программ пишется для работы с данными, которые идут из сети. А при таком подходе пользователю отдается лишь клиентская часть, которая занимается исключительно их (данных) "отрисовкой" (отображением). Все самое ценное остается на сервере и, по сути, оно не досягаемо. Ну а ценного на клиентской части ничего быть не может, чтобы ради взлома тратить уйму времени и ресурсов.

Comment: Что касается непосредственно передачи данных, то подавляющее большинство всех передач по сети происходит именно посредством такого абстрактного понятия как сокет. Сокетом для простоты считайте  пару чисел ip-адрес/порт. С какого-то сокета данные уходят и на какой-то сокет приходят. А уже какая-то программа на той или иной конечной точке слушает указанный ей сокет. И если программа уже слушает сокет, то другая программа воспользоваться этой парой не сможет.

Comment: Передаются по сети просто наборы байт. А вот тот порядок байт и данных, который будет понятен обеим сторонам (и клиенту и серверу), называется протоколом. TCP и UDP - это протоколы. Но их внутренняя реализация хоть и открыта, все же не используется пользователем. На основании этих протоколов пишется уже, как правило, собственный протокол обмена данными. Так HTTP - это протокол, написанный поверх протокола TCP (как и многие другие - HTTPS, WS, FTP, SMTP, SSH...).

Comment: Из всего выше изложенного можно попробовать вывести следующие моменты... Если хотите создать больше проблем с клиентским кодом, то пишите его изначально на компилируемом в машинный код языке. Для обмена данными между клиентом и сервером используйте свой протокол и передавайте бинарные данные. Тогда придется еще и с протоколом разбираться. На клиенте производите исключительно отображение данных - всю обработку данных переносите на сервер. Все поступающие на сервер данные проверяются. Собираетесь использовать готовые решения? - значит алгоритм работы части итогового кода уже будет известен всем.

Comment: @MaxZS И как свой протокол мне представить ?

Comment: Это уже как и что Вы придумаете - так и будет. Вы же даже не указываете, что пишите. Но в целом, это выглядит так... Есть сервер (пусть он слушает порт 20000) и есть клиент, который подключается к серверу и отправляет данные на этот порт (все это происходит посредством сокетов и протокола TCP). После подключения клиент передает какие-то данные. Вот этот порядок байт и данных и есть Ваш протокол. Например, вы отсылаете на сервер 05 00 57 C8 17 00 D6 07 00 00 0b 40. Только Вы знаете, что первые два байта (число 5) - это номер команды - назовем ее RATING. Следующие четыре байта - это ID клиента.

Comment: ID = 1558615. Следующие два байта - это год рождения клиента YEAR = 2006. Следующие четыре - это число вида float, которое обозначает непосредственно рейтинг клиента и равно 5,50. Точно также по аналогии можете передавать любые команды. Это упрощенная схема. Желательно еще вначале посылать какой-либо маркер начала пакета и длину пакета в байтах (хотя и не обязательно). Но в целом эту структуру будете знать только Вы.

Comment: @MaxZS но ведь она идет без крипта, да и ко всему прочему если я хочу передать скомпилированную программу, ее тоже по протоколу передавать ?

Comment: Можете все что угодно передавать: можете один байт, а можете и гигабайт, можете текст, а можете и программу. Разницы что передавать абсолютно нет никакой. Передаются байты. А что Вы хотите получить от криптования? Пример... Криптования нет. Передаем данные от сервера к клиенту. Данные: 05 00 12. Что я передал? А если я уберу пояснения из предыдущего примера, то "догадаетесь" ли Вы вообще когда-нибудь что это был за набор из 12 байт?

Comment: Шифрование нужно, но проблема в том, что если клиент доступен для декомпиляции, то ключи шифрования оттуда всегда можно вытащить. Нужно соотнести сложность защиты с ценностью программы. А то окажется, что и вовсе защищать ничего не нужно

Comment: @gecube А вы случайно не вкурсе что можно использовать как основу для таких приложений ?

Comment: @MaxZS  Мне нужно что-то уже готовое в этом направлении( браузер или просто GUI С вводом логина пароля и вся сопутствующая структура ) Ибо на сколько я понял если делать как в Steam(Встроенный браузер) то придется делать на моем CMS - полноценные ссылки, из плюсов - юзер не может ничего подменить или добавить от себя - так ведь ) ?